# SELECT DISTINCT isn't querying me DISTINCT values

Tags: c#, sql-server, select

I'm using this query in order to get some records from a MSSQL database and fill a combobox.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ta.Marca,
  ta.IDTipAutocar
FROM TipAutocar ta
INNER JOIN Autocare a
  ON ta.idtipautocar = a.idtipautocar
```

In table *Marca* from the database, I have multiple names (eg. Mercedes - appears several times) and when I open my form and dropdown the combo list, I see all the values from database, including duplicates. Any ideas?

Comment: DISTINCT is applied to all fields of your query not just to the first one. So you need to have DISTINCT values for the columns Marca and IDTipAutocar

Comment: You should include an example, what's in the table, what are you getting now and what do you expect as a result -- that way the answers would be better

Comment: @JamesZ - I'm having in the column `IDTipAutocar` values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and in the column `Manufacturer` values (Mercedes, Fiat, Volkswagen, Fiat, Mercedes) and I would like to get distinct value, not all duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to get all DISTINCT combinations of Marca and IDTipAutocar, so if you have multiple tips for Mercedes  you will see it multiple times.

If you show an example data set and the desired result we can suggest how best to achieve.

Comment: Would he also be getting any combinations of Marca, IDTipAutocar, as well as all combinations present in the link between TipAutocar and Autocare tables? He's joined Autocare, but does not use it in the query.

Comment: I'm having in the column `IDTipAutocar` values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and in the column `Manufacturer` values (Mercedes, Fiat, Volkswagen, Fiat, Mercedes) and I would like to get distinct value, not all duplicates.

Comment: @rrrrdc: So if those are the values, there are not "duplicate rows," even though there are duplicate values in Manufacturer. If you remove IDTipAutocar you would get on Mercedes, Fiat, Volkswagen back.